# Android - when to unregister broadCastListener for SCREEN_ON/OFF?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have an Activity with the following onCreate().

What I want is that only in this specific Activity, detect whether the screen is locked or unlocked, and perform a certain stuff accordingly.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
    receiver = new ScreenLockListener();
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

    setFragment(new CamcorderFragment().setBundle(getIntent().getExtras()), false);
}
```

Since the above three actions can only be received by receivers registered by Java code (not in AndroidManifest.xml), I want to know WHEN I should register and unregister the above receiver.

If I register in the onCreate() and not unregister, it works fine.

If I register in the onCreate() and unregister in the onDestroy() then it doesn't behave correctly because there is no receiver between the execution of onDestroy() and next onCreate() within the activity.

Is it okay if I just keep register the same receiver in the onCreate and not unregister? Does it affect memory management?

If I am wrong, where should I register and unregister the receiver that will only be alive as long as the user doesn't leave this Activity (even though onCreate and onDestory will be called several times?)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you register your broadcastreceiver in your manifest?

Comment: For above three Intents, you can only register the receiver in Java code, not in Manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should register the filters in `onResume()` and unregister in `onPause()`. while unregistering in `onPause()` check if the activity is finishing with `isFinishing()`.

However, there could be cases when user leaves your application by pressing home button, in which case `isFinishing()` returns `false`. In order to handle such cases unregister the filters in `onDestroy()` as well, just make sure to catch `IllegalArgumentException` there.

Comment: Like I said, if I unregister it in onPause() then how will it handle the lock/unlock between onPause() and the next onResume() where there is no receiver?

Comment: `isFinishing()` returns false if 1) your app is in foreground, or 2) the user leaves the app by pressing home button. i.e., filter unregister block will not be called in `onPause()` at such cases. That's the reason you need to have unregister code in `onDestroy()`, too (so that your app gets cleaned properly and won't leak any memory). Hence, you will be able to handle screen on/off events just like the way you are doing now. The key difference here is registering the filter in `onCreate()` vs `onResume()`. You should use the latter.